# How can I derive from a base class and implement an interface in C#?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class ContentService : IContentService
```

I would like to make a BaseService class and implement some common functionality there. However I would also like to still implement all the IContentService methods.

How can I modify this line so it both implements the interface and inherits from BaseService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit your class from both base class and interface. Implementing interface in base class provides you with option to not implement all the interface methods. Like following example:

```
interface ITestInterface
{
    void Test();
    string Test2();
}

public class TestBase : ITestInterface
{
    #region ITestInterface Members

    public void Test()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Feed");
    }

    public string Test2()
    {
        return "Feed";
    }

    #endregion
}

public class TestChild : TestBAse, ITestInterface
{
    public void Test()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Feed1");
    }
}

public static void Main(){
    TestChild f = new TestChild();
    f.Test();

    var i = f as ITestInterface;

    i.Test();
    i.Test2();//not implemented in child but called from base.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public class ContentService: BaseService, IContentService
{
}
```

You can add as many interfaces as you want, and up to one base class in the list. Just use a comma to separate each additional interface.

The base class doesn't need to be the first item in the list, either.

Answer (score 1):

`public class ContentService: BaseService, IContentService`

Will inherit from BaseService and implement your IContentService interface.

You may also want to look up Abstract classes/methods for your base class.